# LTspice current regulator analysis with MOSFETs and BJT

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, bjt, ltspice, current-limiting

I ran the transient analysis for the this circuit with NMOS and NPN respectively. Once with the NPN BJT, the results look reasonable. The current through R1 is about 20mA. When I change to NMOS, the results are about 0.2mA.

What did I miss for using a NMOS in an op-amp analysis?

[image: circuit with NMOS]

Comment: Shouldn't you be using atleast vsupply of 6V for OP07 because datasheet says min supply voltage is +/-3V? Coming to the problem you are facing, I guess that the VTH of the nmos is too high that the loop is out of regulation. Keep increasing vsupply and see at what voltage you get the expected output current

Comment: I would say the VTH is too low.  Default `NMOS` model uses VTH=0V.  You should *always* select an actual part number for all discrete semiconductor devices, especially for MOSFETs.  Right-click the symbol and select a part# which is close to what you need.  If you're unsure, just pick a 2N7002 for now.

Answer (score 6):

A BJT requires only 0.7V to allow current from collector  to emitter.

A MOSFET can require a gate-source threshold voltage, VGSth, to be at least 4V to allow drain current of only 250 microamps. Adding to the voltage across the source resistor would require at least 6V at the gate. For 20mA, a little higher.

VGSth varies from below 1 volt to as high as 4 volts depending on the device. You must read the data sheet.

The operational amplifier supply is only 5V. Increasing the supply voltage to a value higher than VGSth is required. Many op-amps cannot work close the the supply rail vaoltages. The supply voltage must be increased to accomodatethis as well.

As a side point also mentioned in a comment, the op-amp chosen for simulation requires at least 6V rail-to-rail.

---

I have also found that the NMOS model is not very good. Choose a particular device.

Answer (score 5):

I see two* things wrong with this circuit:

First, the OP07 Can, at best, only drive to within 2.2V of the rails, and at worst, 3V (see the "voltage output swing" line in the datasheet, and remember that they're powering the thing from \$\pm 15\mathrm V\$).  I'm actually a bit surprised that your BJT version is working.

Second, the enhancement-mode MOSFETs that are commonly on the market today need some voltage to turn on **and** as already mentioned, the generic transistor models (FET or BJT) are not reliable.

As for remedies: first, choose a different op-amp.  Make sure it has a rail-rail output, or nearly so.

If for some reason you're entirely committed to the OP07 and a FET, try using a pull-up resistor on the output of the OP07 -- like most bipolar, non rail-to-rail op-amps, it has a class-B output stage.  If you help the upper, PNP half with a pull-up resistor, the output may be able to go higher.  (Note that I haven't tried this with the OP07 specifically, but I've used it, or seen it work, on a number of other similar chips).

Second, choose a FET with a sufficiently low threshold voltage so that it'll work.  In this case you can probably get by with a logic-level FET that's designed to switch fully on with a \$\mathrm {V_{GS}}\$ of 3.3V.  Because gate capacitance is a detriment to stability in circuits like this, choose the smallest FET you can find that's otherwise suitable.

---

* Three if you count that, typically, a circuit like this, realized with a unity-gain stable op-amp, will be unstable due to the amplifier being loaded by the FET's gate capacitance.  It doesn't *always* happen, but it happens enough that there are several questions on this site about how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to know what's wrong with your circuit. Click on the opamp output. If it is close to opamp supply rail or GND, you are saturating your opamp.

I checked the OP07 datasheet. Its maximum voltage swing at +-15V supply is +-13V. Therefore, we can approximately know its maximum voltage swing at +5V supply is +2V~+3V.

The 100ohm resistor has 2V on it. The Vbe is about 0.7V. So the opamp has to output about 2.7V to make the BJT version work. Luckily you get the opamp work in its available output range.

As to the NMOS version, NMOS takes about 2V to 4V to conduct. So the opamp has to output about 2+2V to 2+4V. Seems both are out of the maximum output range.

I suggest providing opamp with the 12V.